# How to use overprint with align environment in latex beamer?

Tags: beamer, align, overlays

I want to use the Latex beamer overprint feature given by the overprint-environment for a multi-line math formula typeset with the align*-environemnt within which I want to change certain contents on different slides.

However, when I try a construction as in the minimal example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{align*}
         f(x) &= 
            \begin{overprint}
               \onslide<1-2> x^2-2x+1
               \onslide<3-4> (x-1)^2
            \end{overprint} 
      \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get a "Missing $ inserted." message upon compilation, and the overprint didn't work.

No doubt this has something to do with that

> align does wicked things

(Beamer user guide p. 23)
However for now I refuse to accept that there should be no possibility to replace parts of a multi-line displayed formula (aka align*). Unfortunately I cannot use the workaround described on p 219 of the beamer user guide (use `\uncover` instead of  `\onslide`) and also `\only` as I want to replace parts of the formula without changing other parts, also not the other parts' positions. (Avoid "wobbling" of typeset material.)

So how can I achieve what overprint does in non-align* environments within those?

Alternatively: How can I avoid align* and still have multi-line formulas nicely aligned at certain points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution proved to be quite easy - put the text within the overprint-environment again in math mode. I don't understand why it took me a while to figure it out.

So changing the above environment to

```
\begin{overprint}
   \onslide<1-2> $x^2-2x+1$ 
   \onslide<3-4> $(x-1)^2
\end{overprint}
```

did the trick. Apparently, within an `overprint`-environment math mode is no longer active.